# Unicode list to integer list conversion in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have used map to convert a string/unicode list to an integer list in Python, when the list is like `[u'94',u'95',u'8',u'7',u'0']`.

But if I have a list like this `[u'94,95,8,7,0']`, how can it be converted to an integer list?

Map or int(x) conversion using a for loop is not working. It's throwing this error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '94,95,8,7,0'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a=[u'94,95,8,7,0']
# print(map(int,a)) -> here reproduces your error because 
# '94,95,8,7,0' is not a valid value
b = a[0].split(',')
print(b) # [u'94', u'95', u'8', u'7', u'0']

c = map(int,b)
print(c) # [94, 95, 8, 7, 0]
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked!! simple but couldnt get that hint before